# Tens of thousands of htm files in c:\Temp

Tags: visual-studio-2022

VS 2022 creates tens of thousands of htm-files (obviuosly log-files) in c:\Temp\Default and c:\Temp\NativeImage.
After a couple of weeks of work with VS they add upp to several GB. This slows down work as the Virus scanner will take all cpu for several minutes after starting VS.
Deleting those folders and I'm back to normal for a week or so. And is not good for my SSD.
What can be done to prevent this?
I havn't seen this with VS2019 or early versions of VS2022.

Comment: Are you sure that it's VS that's creating these files, not your own application? What is in the files?

Comment: I used process monitor to check this. And I dont have to load any solution to get a couple of hundred files. Content are similar to this:

Assembly manager loaded from:  C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework64\v4.0.30319\clr.dll
Running under executable  C:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio\2022\Community\Common7\IDE\devenv.exe
--- A detailed error log follows. 
=== Pre-bind state information ===
LOG: DisplayName = Accessibility, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a
 (Fully-specified)
LOG: Appbase = file:///C:/Program Files/Microsoft Visual Studio/2022/...

Answer (score 0):

From your comment, this sounds like logs from the Fusion Log Viewer.  Double-check your settings by running fuslogvw.exe from an elevated command prompt (need to be elevated to change settings).

[image: Fusion Log Viewer settings]

If you have enabled either of the last 2 options (Log bind failures to disk or Log all binds to disk), it will create a log file for each applicable event.  This can end up consuming lots of disk space, as you're observing.

If you set it to the second option (Log in exception text), you'll be able to view these details in the debugger if you're encountering assembly bind failures, but it doesn't write to disk anywhere (just a slight memory increase in the exception objects).

Comment: This was definitely the problem. I wasn't aware that this was installed by default with VS and the settings must have been changed at some VS Update as I did not know they were there. Log all binds to disk was enabled.
Thank you for the solution.